# Adding Action to button in HTML

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<html>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<head>
<title>Sarvotam List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="seg">
    <form action="main.jsp" method="post">
    <table class="data" align="center" width=80%>
        <tr>
            <th width=20%>Qualification Exam</th>       
            <th width=20%>Course Type</th>
            <th width=20%>Duration</th>
            <th width=20%>Number of Cheques</th>
            <th width=20%>Course_Category</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="text" name="qual" 
  width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="text" name="ctype" 
  width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="number" name="dur" 
  width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="number" name="che" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><select name="opt">
                    <option id="ENG">ENG</option>
                    <option id="MED">MED</option>
                    <option id="OTH">OTH</option>
                    <option id="PG">PG</option>
                </select>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="text" name="qual" 
 width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="text" name="ctype" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="number" name="dur" 
     width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="number" name="che" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><select name="opt">
                    <option id="ENG">ENG</option>
                    <option id="MED">MED</option>
                    <option id="OTH">OTH</option>
                    <option id="PG">PG</option>
                </select>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="text" name="qual" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="text" name="ctype" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="number" name="dur" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="number" name="che" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><select name="opt">
                    <option id="ENG">ENG</option>
                    <option id="MED">MED</option>
                    <option id="OTH">OTH</option>
                    <option id="PG">PG</option>
                </select>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="text" name="qual" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="text" name="ctype" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="number" name="dur" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="number" name="che" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><select name="opt">
                    <option id="ENG">ENG</option>
                    <option id="MED">MED</option>
                    <option id="OTH">OTH</option>
                    <option id="PG">PG</option>
                </select>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="text" name="qual" 
  width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="text" name="ctype" 
 width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="number" name="dur" 
    width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><input type="number" name="che" 
width=20%></td>
            <td width=20% align="center"><select name="opt">
                    <option id="ENG">ENG</option>
                    <option id="MED">MED</option>
                    <option id="OTH">OTH</option>
                    <option id="PG">PG</option>
                </select>
        </tr>
            </table>
        <center><button id="submit" name="save">Submit</button></center>

<%              try{
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Statement st=null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = 
   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", 
   "system", "parents94");
            st=conn.createStatement();
            int i=0;
            String s = request.getParameter("save");
            String[] qual=request.getParameterValues("qual");
            String[] ctype=request.getParameterValues("ctype");
            String[] dur=request.getParameterValues("dur");
            String[] noc=request.getParameterValues("che");
            String[] cou=request.getParamterValues("opt");
            if(s!=null)
            while(qual[i].length()!=0){
                st.executeUpdate("insert into SCHOL_COURSE_MASTER values('"+qual[i]+"','"+ctype[i]+"','"+dur[i]+"','"+noc[i]+"','"+cou[i]+"')");
                i++;
            }
        conn.close();
        st.close(); 
            }
catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }
%>
</form> 
</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

This is my code
I need to take inputs from user in the table and add to the database
All the connections work
But the sql query does not lead to any changes in the data base
I just need help in how to code it to work on press of submit button

Comment: The DB update related code is available on same jsp? Where is your main.jsp related code? Never ever use scriptlets on jsp. Keep the query logs and try to see what query is going to execute in DB.

Answer (score 3):

Add submit type to button:

```
<center>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="save">Submit</button>
</center>
```

Comment: your form action should be the file with the code you want to run

Answer (score 0):

first you might want to check if
the click event was triggered?

then try to print if the you get the correct values or if it is not null

if you there are error its better if you include it in your post

Comment: there are no errors as such but it doesnt work
and can you tell me how to check if the click event was triggered

Comment: it was in the <form action="main.jsp">

check if data inside the main.jsp is correct